# Adding delay while Mediaplayer loops

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Playing `.wav` file using `MediaPlayer` class. As I need to loop the Audio I've set `.setLooping(true);` .  So obviously, the doubt is how do I add a delay each time the audio plays, say I want a delay of `5000` .

The answers to similar questions here doesn't work in my case. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
 Button Sample = (Button)findViewById(R.id.samplex);
    Sample.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myAppCache/wakeUp.wav";

            try {
                mp.setDataSource(filePath);
                mp.prepare();
                mp.setLooping(true);

            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();

        }


    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register 2 listeners (on completion and on error) and then you would need to delay next play in on completion callback. Reason for the error listener is to return `true` to avoid calling on completion event whenever there is an error - explanation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html#onError%28android.media.MediaPlayer,int,int)

```
private final Runnable loopingRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mp != null) {
            if (mp.isPlaying() {
                mp.stop();
            }
            mp.start();
        }
    }
}

mp.setDataSource(filePath);
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        button.postDelayed(loopingRunnable, 5000);
    }
});
mp.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    ...
    return true;
});

mp.prepare();
// no need to loop it since on completion event takes care of this
// mp.setLooping(true);
```

Whenever your destruction method is (`Activity.onDestroyed(), Fragment.onDestroy(), View.onDetachedFromWindow()`), ensure you are removing the runnable callbacks, e.g.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ...
    button.removeCallbacks(loopingRunnable);

    if (mp != null) {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
        }

        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}
```