# Using Timer in MediaPlayer does not work

Tags: android

I am trying to create a delay for an Audio file that I am repeatedly playing.
However, the code doesn't seems to have any effect whatsoever. Here is my code:

```
     try {
        mp.setDataSource(text);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.setVolume(0.5f,0.5f);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
            {


                final Handler h = new Handler();
                h.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    private long time = 0;

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {

                        time += 1000;
                        Log.d("TimerExample", "Going for... " + time);
                        h.postDelayed(this, 5000);
                    }
                }, 5000);


            }
        });
```

Any fix/solution would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247607/adding-delay-while-mediaplayer-loops

Mainly you have to use listener like this

```
private final Runnable loopingRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mp != null) {
            if (mp.isPlaying() {
                mp.stop();
            }
            mp.start();
        }
    }
}

mp.setDataSource(filePath);
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        button.postDelayed(loopingRunnable, 5000);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is `button` in `button.postDelayed()` , I am not using any buttons to start the Timer,

Comment: please try to add mp.postDelayed(loopingRunnable, 5000);

Comment: That was my first instinct, however it results in error !